# rails carrierwave, upload multiple files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first question [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46924133/685060).

I tried to modify upload multiple files at once.

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@attractions) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name, t("attraction.name"), class: "col-md-2 control-label" %>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.fields_for :attraction_photos do |att_photo| %>
          <%= att_photo.label :photo, t("attraction.attraction_photo"), class: "col-md-2 control-label" %>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <%= att_photo.file_field :photo, class: "form-control", multiple: true %> // <==== I add this
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

**attraction_controller**

```
def new
  @attractions = Attraction.new
  @attractions.attraction_photos.build
end

def create
  @attractions = current_user.attractions.build(attraction_params)

  if @attractions.save
    flash[:success] = "success"
    redirect_to attractions_path
  else
    flash[:danger] = @attractions.errors.full_messages
    render action: :new
  end
end

def attraction_params
  params.require(:attraction).permit(:name, :longitude, :latitude, :address, :phone, :category_id, attraction_photos_attributes: [:photo => []])
end
```

I got the params is

```
{
    "name" => "name", 
    "longitude" => "111",
    "latitude" => "222", 
    "address" => "addresss", 
    "phone" => "phone", 
    "category_id" => "1", 
     "attraction_photos_attributes" => {
        "0" => {
            "photo" => [#, @original_filename = "aaaaaaaaaaaa.png", @content_type = "image/png", @headers = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attraction[attraction_photos_attributes][0][photo][]\"; filename=\"aaaaaaaaaaaa.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n" > , #, @original_filename = "bbbbbbbbbbb.png", @content_type = "image/png", @headers = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attraction[attraction_photos_attributes][0][photo][]\"; filename=\"bbbbbbbbbbb.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n" > ]
        }
    }
}
```

I think I should use a loop to create photos. But the data structure isn't I want. Thanks for your help.

**Eidt**

**attraction model**

```
class Attraction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :attraction_photos, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attraction_photos

  ...
end
```

**attraction photo model**

```
class AttractionPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attraction

  mount_uploader :photo, AttractionImageUploader
end
```

Comment: Please share your model code.

Comment: @Vishal i updated

Comment: Have you refered [this](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two options

first option use a `json` field in your db to upload the pictures. Not all db allow this, for example some `mysql2` db do not allow you to use the `json` type field in your db. Also using this is not the ruby on rails best practice

[rails carrierwave, one user has many image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924133/rails-carrierwave-one-user-has-many-image)

The other option is from this solution, you will not use a JSON field in the db, but create a separate table

[Rails 4 multiple image or file upload using carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411988/rails-4-multiple-image-or-file-upload-using-carrierwave)

now please tell me why you do not want to use either this solutions, because I implemented both and I will try to help you

Also from your question it is not clear the issue you are having

Comment: I just want practice. And I'm not familiar with DB store picture, and I just want to upload the picture file. That's all.

Comment: @lighter thanks a lot let me know if you need some help